# REST - multiple input to create same resource

Tags: rest, post, resources

I'm modelling REST api set manage a resource (example: Person).
I need to expose the capability to create a Person:

- providing data in body payload: POST /Person body:{name:"John", surname:"Doe"}
- providing data as multipart/form-data via file: POST /Person multipart/form-data {@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
  @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail}

This means the same HTTP Verb + path for both apis.
Now if I try to generate OpenAPI 3.0 docs I will fail because http + path must be unique.

What is the REST way to model these 2 way to create a resource?

And after, the tricky part, below my two jersey2 endpoints:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Operation( tags = {"Import"},
            summary = "Import from file path",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "202", description = "Import accepted",
                        content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, schema = @Schema(implementation = ImportRepresentation.class))),
            })
    public Response importFromFilePath(@RequestBody( description = "Import from file path", required = true,
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ImportFileRequest.class))) ImportFileRequest importFileRequest)
            {

.......
        return response;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation( tags = {"Import"},
                summary = "Import provided file",
                responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "202", description = "Import accepted",
                            content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, schema = @Schema(implementation = ImportRepresentation.class))),
            })
    public Response importUploadedFile(
            @Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "file", format = "binary", description = "file"))
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,

            @Parameter(hidden = true)
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,

            @Parameter(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class), required = false)
            @FormDataParam("commitMessage") String commitMessage)
            {

        ........

            return response;
    }
```

How can I annotate them to generate OpenAPI.yaml with two `requestBody.content` entries?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the REST way to model these 2 way to create a resource?

As far as [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) is concerned, using the same HTTP method and target URI for both cases is *fine*.

On the web, this might look like two different HTML forms; one form with input controls to collect name and surname, the other with input controls for copying a file.  In both cases, submitting the form would cause the browser to produce a POST request to the target URI described by the form itself (ie: form.action).

---

From the OpenApi 3.0.3 specification, the treatment that describes this approach would be a single method and target URI, but with multiple media type entries in the requestBody.content map.  See the sections in the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/specification/)  describing the `Request Body Object` and `Media Type Object`.

Comment: Thanks!

I updated the question with another topic, Operation annotations related.

Comment: "How can I annotate them to generate OpenAPI.yaml with two requestBody.content entries?" -- My opinion...?  That's a really great question all by itself and you should probably separate it out.  I haven't the foggiest idea what the answer might be.

Comment: To check that the OpenAPI.yaml syntax with tow entries in requestBody.content (application/json and multipart/form-data), I tried to generate server code from that and generated interface (jersey2) has only one method accepting the "application/json" way, nothing related to the "multipart/form-data".
Now I'm not sure that OpenAPI syntax is the right one.
I split annotation request there: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445547/how-to-annotate-jersey2-overloaded-endpoints-to-generate-openapi-yaml)

Comment: Update: looks like that OpenAPI.yaml syntax is fine, multiple entries in requestBody:content. OpenAPI generator generates the 2 api for the client but now able to manage this for jersey 2 server.

Comment: So it's a really great question AND you might be able to provide an answer.  Sweet.